# Re-stream shoutcast stream

Tags: audio, mp3, streaming, shoutcast

Basically I want to 'Re-stream' a shoutcast stream.
MP3 stream that is.

Tried searching around but couldn't find a way to do this. (It's an internet radio where only some of my friends get it without lag, so they could restream it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a lot about Shotcast and if you want to stream through that, I don't know what to suggest.

If you are saying that you have a `MP3` file and you want to stream that, I would recommend either [Windows Media Services](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/server/server.aspx) off of Windows Server if you have a spare box lying around, or even just using [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org) - it has an excellent built in streamer.

Comment: I have no Windows Server atm, nor Windows media player (thats the first thing I remove after a fresh install). I tried VNC but I can't find the option if I start listening to the stream I want to restream. oO

Comment: Forget what I said: Copying the URL into stream just works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do a proper relay of an existing stream I'd suggest installing SHOUTcast locally or on a hosted server (if your host allows it). Then take a look at sc_trans (SHOUTcast DNAS Transcoder 2), which allows relaying and can even be installed as a service and scheduled with a cron job if there's a show you're looking to relay automatically every day/week. We used this to relay a weekly show out of Toronto for awhile.

These links should help you get started:

[SHOUTcast Download](https://radiomanager.shoutcast.com/register/serverSoftwareFreemium) (Linux 32/64 & Windows 32/64)

[SHOUTcast Installation](https://help.shoutcast.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002843414-Installation)

[SHOUTcast DNAS Transcoder](http://wiki.shoutcast.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_DNAS_Transcoder_2)