# The ability to play music from 1 computer and hear it playing on another computer

Tags: home-networking, internet-radio, music-streaming

I don't know what this is called or if this even exists.

But i'm looking for a way to for example play music on one computer and have other computers listen in to it like a Radio where one computer is the DJ and have this work on the local Home network.

I don't want to play music over speakers throughout the house, but I want to let people who want to listen be able to do it on their computers using their headphones.

Again this preferably should work well in a LAN set up since I would only use this in my home.

Any help in finding the best solution would be great thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-stream shoutcast stream](http://superuser.com/questions/225716/re-stream-shoutcast-stream) also see [Streaming music throughout the house on a budget?](http://superuser.com/questions/111325/streaming-music-throughout-the-house-on-a-budget?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Airfoil Speakers](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) allows you to play iTunes or Airfoil output on any computer. The DJ computer in your example is in full control with no intervention from the client. Airfoil Speakers is free but only with purchase of Airfoil (for $25).

Comment: yup this seems like what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The term you are looking for is [Streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media).

You will need both a program running on the server to create the stream and a program running on the clients to play the audio out. A good free program that can do both sides is [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html) (they have a dedicated streaming server program, however the client can stream too, the wiki has [documentation](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo_New#Streaming) on how to set it up.)

Comment: +1 for pointing out what it's called.  Interestingly, it appears the OP managed to tag it [music-streaming] on his own? :)

Comment: I thought streaming was when you could select which music you can play. Not what I want, I was looking more for a Radio type situation where one server I guess in this case would play some playlist and others would, yes, stream whatever the playlist has. So Music Radio Streaming In Home could be the term i'm looking for ;)